# Gostaria de saber como funciona o SQlite

Tags: python, sqlite

Minha duvida é o seguinte:

> Se os dados do banco de dados ficam armazenados num **arquivo.db** no meu computador. Ou externamente.

Comment: O SQLite não foi planejado para competir com SGBDs do modelo cliente-servidor. Se quiser deixar seu banco de dados em um servidor ao qual os clientes se conectem existem opções melhores como por exemplo: Oracle, PostgrSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, etc

Comment: Mas assim, sabendo SQL você consegue usar qualquer um desses? Ou a **syntax** vai mudar?

Comment: O dialeto SQL pode ter ligeiras mudanças de acordo com o SGBD. O PostgreSQL é um dos mais aderentes ao padrão SQL.

Answer (score 0):

No seu computador, para que seja externamente ele deve estar em um servidor apropriado. Segue exemplos de alguns:
Oracle. 
SQL Server.
MySQL.
PostgreSQL.
IBM DB2.
NoSQL.

SQL é a linguagem padrão ANSI para a manipulação de bancos de dados relacionais. Por ser um padrão aceito pela indústria, é suportada por todos os SGBD's relacionais - o que inclui produtos como Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite e IBM DB2.